# How to use jquery selector to add an open div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using .after() to add html closing and open tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706457/using-after-to-add-html-closing-and-open-tags)

I am in need of adding some HTML before a `<li>` and after the same `<li>`.

The selector works, but when it adds the HTML it also closes the `<div>`s with adding `</div>`. I need it to be open.

my code:

```
$('#ja-megamenu .level1').before('<div class="childcontent cols1 ">');
```

NOTE:
I need it to add ONLY `<div class="childcontent cols1 ">` before the `li` (with class="level1")

then later I'll use:

```
 $('#ja-megamenu .level1').after('</div>');
```

to add the closing `</div>`

This code doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

Have been reading documentation all day long, but haven't found the answer yet...

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this HTML is not valid (`<li>`'s parent could not be `<div>`), you may use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$("#ja-megamenu .level1").wrap("<div class='childcontent cols1' />");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I also wrote an error in my question: I wanted tp wrap an UL not an LI. :-)

Comment: @Netthandel That makes more sense. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not do that, if you want to add a div around an element, use [jQuery's wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('#ja-megamenu .level1').wrap('<div class="childcontent cols1 "></div>');
```

BUT the problem you have is a div can not wrap an li! You need to do something else.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

My bad, I meant an UL :-)

Comment: Still got a problem that the drop down is not working, but that is another case :-)

Comment: A correction: This worked, but folowing the documentation I need to not add </div> in the .wrap()

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**wrap**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), if you want your html with the you are try to add before and after.

```
$('#ja-megamenu .level1').wrap('<div class="childcontent cols1 ">');
```

Answer (score 1):

use wrap...

```
$('#ja-megamenu .level1').wrap('<div class="childcontent cols1">');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you this is invalid operation, because you cannot add `div` before or after an `li`,

the `li` element must be in `ul` or `ol` container and its siblings must be `li`.

so try to change your structure : maybe put the `div` inside the `li`

```
<ul>
    <li class="level1"><div></div></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

$('.level1').prepend('<div> Your content here</div>');
```

Comment: Not only `<ul>` could be the container, but also `<ol>`.

Comment: @VisionN you are right i will edit my answer

Comment: My bad, I meant an ul :-)

This was a good solution for an li though :-)