# jQuery append() not adding </ul><ul>

Tags: jquery, html-lists, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using .after() to add html closing and open tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706457/using-after-to-add-html-closing-and-open-tags)

I want to show 3 columns lists (`<ul>`) with almost the same height, so I'm counting the `<li>` tags and use append to generate the list dynamically. But when I do `$el.append($("</ul><ul class='new'>"))` to close the current list and append a new one it appends like `<ul class='new'></ul>`.

I just want to close the `<ul>` tag and open it again. Is jQuery `append()` function validating somehow the DOM structure? How can I get the spected result? Any better way to achieve this?

#### HTML:

```
<div id="mylist">
   here the list will show
</div>
```

#### Jquery:

```
var $el = $("#mylist");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$el.append($("<ul class='new'>"));
var j = parseInt(response.length/3);
var i = 0;
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
  i++;
  if(i%j==0){
      $el.append($("</ul><ul class='new'>")).append($("<li></li>").text(value.nombre));
  }
  else{
     $el.append($("<li></li>").text(value.name));
  }});
```

#### Expected result:

```
<div >
   <ul class="new">
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
   </ul><ul class="new"> //This is what I want to append
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
   </ul><ul class="new">
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
     <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

#### What I got:

```
<div id="mylist">
<ul class="new"></ul>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <ul class="new"></ul>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <ul class="new"></ul> 
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
 <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</div>
```

Comment: That kind of formatting with jQ is still not allowed, but there's a way through

Comment: `.append` is for append nodes to the DOM, not arbitrary HTML strings.

Comment: `$("</ul><ul class='new'>")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: "Spected?" What does that mean?

Comment: @Doorknob probably "excpected"

Comment: @roXon: Is possible to do this using `appendChild`?

Comment: @TomSarduy you could simply include a modulus `%3` operator in your "loop story"

Comment: How about you remove $ before "</ul><ul class='new'>"?

Comment: @Martinsos: I tried that but still not working

Comment: @Doorknob: Spected mean expected in spanglish ;) fixed

Comment: What I don't understand is why don't you make the <li> items the same height each, and float them instead? What does the class new do?

Comment: @MarcoBerrocal: Instead having a long unordered list, I want to generate 3 unordered list with the same height (when height is li items count)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Inconceivable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umikom/23/edit)**</kbd>

Instead of objects, play with `"strings"` to set `</ul><ul>` where needed.

```
var arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14'];

var str = "<ul class='new'>";
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;) { 
              str += "<li>"+ arr[i++] +"</li>" ;  
  if(i%3===0) str += "</ul><ul class='new'>"   ;
}
str += "</ul>" ;

$("#mylist").html( str );
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, I promise to use `.html()` instead `append()` for this kind of task

Answer (score 5):

First, it's important to note that `append`ing is a much more computationally expensive operation than setting `innerHTML` on an element.  Second, it's important to note that jQuery parses HTML strings (e.g. `$('<ul />');` ) into DOM elements via `document.createElement`.  In other words, it's not like concatenating a string; you cannot create partial elements.

What you want is to build an HTML string with raw string concatenation, then dump that into the DOM via `innerHTML`.  For example:

```
var colHTML = [];
var numPerCol = Math.ceil(response.length/3);
var i=0;
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    var curCol = Math.floor(i / numPerCol);
    if (i % numPerCol == 0)
        colHTML[curCol] = '';
    colHTML[curCol] += '<li>' + value.nombre + '</li>'; // if nombre has invalid HTML, you need to escape it
});

var html = '<ul class="new">' + colHTML.join('</ul><ul class="new">') + '</ul>';
document.getElementById('mylist').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the explanation, the code is working fine, but i selected the @roXon answer because the code is more simple

Answer (score 4):

`$('</ul><ul>')` isn't going to do what you think. It will try to create a DOM element, probably resulting in a `<ul>`.

You'll have to build each element you need and piece them together, or operate on the html as a string using `.html()`. I definitely recommend the first of these options.

Comment: thanks, I will try with `.html()` to see what happens ;)

Comment: +1, but I selected the @roXon answer because is more complete (plus code)