# How do I insert a new div between an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert a new div after the second list item. But I also want to close the `</ol>` before it and open a new `<ol>` right after it.

**This:**

```
<ol>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
    <li>test 4</li>
</ol>
```

**Should become this:**

```
<ol>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
</ol>
<div>NEW DIV</div>
<ol>
    <li>test 3</li>
    <li>test 4</li>
</ol>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var el = $('ol li:eq(1)');

el.after('<div>NEW DIV</div>');
```

Here's my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/

Is there any way to do this with jQuery?

I already tried to do `after('</ol><div>NEW DIV</div><ol>)` but that obviously does not work, as it has been discussed here: [Using .after() to add html closing and open tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706457/using-after-to-add-html-closing-and-open-tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $lis = $('ol li');
$lis.filter(':lt(2)').unwrap().wrapAll('<ol/>').closest('ol').after('<div>NEW DIV</div>');
$lis.filter(':gt(1)').wrapAll('<ol/>');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCz9W/)**

If you want to chain all of them then:

```
var $lis = $('ol li');
$lis.filter(':lt(2)') //get all the li's with index less than 2 i.e your number
               .unwrap() //unwrap it
               .wrapAll('<ol/>') //wrap them in ol
               .closest('ol').after('<div>NEW DIV</div>').end().end() //append div next to the ol and go back in the chain to the first list of li's
               .filter(':gt(1)') //filter to get remaining items
               .wrapAll('<ol/>'); //wrap them all in a new ol
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URNH9/)**

Comment: Thank you PSL! And btw, there's a period missing before the first `wrapAll`. :)

Comment: @isuckatcoding yeah, infact it happened while i broke down the code for explanation.. Updated :)

Comment: I appreciated the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @isuckatcoding You are welcome... btw change your display name.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $oldOL = $("ol"),
    $newOL = $("<div><ol></ol><div>NEW DIV</div><ol></ol></div>");

$newOL.children().eq(0).append($oldOL.children().slice(0, 2)).end().eq(2).append($oldOL.children().slice(0, 2));

$oldOL.replaceWith($newOL.children());
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/9/

The idea is to create a new set of lists with a div between them and replace the old list with the new HTML structure. The numbers on the ordered list restart now since there are two `<ol />` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's weird that it only works tho when the **whole thing** is wrapped inside a div. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @isuckatcoding That's to make the selectors on the next line simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $('ol li');
var elSize = el.length;
var html = '<ol>';
el.each(function(i){            
    if(i > 0 && i % 2 == 0 && i < elSize) {
      html += '</ol><div>NEW DIV</div><ol>';                  
    }    
    html += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
});
html += '</ol>';
$('body').html(html);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/11/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two lists and insert the new div between them. Here's one of the many ways to do thin by adding the new list before and after the original, then replacing the original with new div:

```
var list = $('ol'), 
    newList = $('<ol />'), 
    items = list.children(), 
    items1 = items.slice(0,2), 
    items2 = items.slice(2), 
    newDiv = $('<div>NEW DIV</div>');
list
 .before( newList.clone().append( items1 ) )
 .after( newList.clone().append( items2 ))
 .replaceWith( newDiv );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/12/

Or, even better! Create a new list, append it after the original, and move a part of list items to it. Then append the new div after the original list.

```
var list = $('ol'), 
    newList = $('<ol />'), 
    items = list.children(),  
    newDiv = $('<div>NEW DIV</div>');
list.after( 
  newList.append( 
    items.slice(2).remove()
  ))
  .after( newDiv );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be help you, It is easy to understand, here i'm doing first find second item of the list the add div on it using append method..

```
$('ol li').eq(1).append('<div>New Div</div>');
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/5hhr2/10/)

Comment: This inserts it inside the second list item.

Comment: this is not what he wants to do. Look at the "Should become this" section