# jQuery .append finishing div on its own?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div `<div id="articles-feed">` into which I'm trying to append some more stuff. I am getting some JSON data which I parse with `JSON.parse`, format a bit and then try to add to my code.

The thing is, the parsed data contains an array of categories, and I need to display all of them, so I figure I'd just do an `.append` 3 times, with a `for-loop` in between to get the relevant data.

Now a strange thing happens when I run my function, a `</div>` gets added after my first `.append`, so the 2nd and 3rd `.append` get added OUTSIDE of the `<div class="article-box">`. If I try to target the class directly using `$('.article-box')` for my 2nd `.append`, nothing happens.

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

My HTML:

```
<div id="articles-sidebar">
    <h2>Search articles archive:</h2>
    <form id="searchbox" method="post">
        <input name="searchword" type="text" placeholder="author, title, keyword...">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="articles-feed">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/articles.js"></script>
```

my jQuery:

```
    for(var x = 0; x<response.length; x++) {
        //format date
        var posted = new Date((response[x].posted * 1000));
        //format extract line brakes
        var extract = response[x].extract.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br>");
        //format categories
        var categories = response[x].cat_name.split(",");
        //append JSON to HTML

        $("#articles-feed").append(
            '<div class="article-box"><h1><a href="#">'+response[x].title+
            '</a></h1><h3><a href="#">' +response[x].name+
            '</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'+ posted.toLocaleDateString()+
            '</h3><ul class="article-categories">');
        for(x=0; x<categories.length;x++) {
            $('#articles-feed').append(
                    '<li class="article-category">' + categories[x] + '</li>'
                ); //end categories append data
                if (categories[x] == "free") {
                    $(".article-box").addClass("free");
                }
        }// end categories append for loop
        $("#articles-feed").append(
            '</ul><p>'+extract+'</p></div>'
            ); //end article feed 3rd append

    } //end article feed for loop
```

Comment: i think some div's are not closing properly

Comment: to close the tags after the title text gets added

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706457/using-after-to-add-html-closing-and-open-tags)

Comment: where is the loop for this one ? ` $("#articles-feed").append(
            '<div class="article-box"><h1><a href="#">'+response[x].title+
            '</a></h1><h3><a href="#">' +response[x].name+
            '</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'+ posted.toLocaleDateString()+
            '</h3><ul class="article-categories">');`

Comment: An `<li>` element is a valid child of only `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements, they cannot be added to any other element types.

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks for the link. I guess I should be using wrap and insert for all 3 appends then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var output = '<div class="article-box"><h1><a href="#">'+response[x].title+
            '</a></h1><h3><a href="#">' +response[x].name+
            '</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'+ posted.toLocaleDateString()+
            '</h3><ul class="article-categories">';
for(x=0; x<categories.length;x++) {
    var output = output + '<li class="article-category">' + categories[x] + '</li>';
    if (categories[x] == "free") {
         $(".article-box").addClass("free");
    }
}
var output = output + '</ul><p>'+extract+'</p></div>';

$("#articles-feed").append(output);
```

This will working. I tried this working for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to append a starting tag and an ending tag. It doesn't work like that, you can only append complete elements.

The starting and ending tags are only used in HTML to describe an element, once it is parsed into an element there are no separate starting and ending parts, it's just a single element.

Create a list element that you can put the categories in:

```
var list = $('<ul>', { className: 'article-categories' });
for(x = 0; x < categories.length; x++) {
  list.append($('<li>', { className: 'article-category' }).text(categories[x]));
  if (categories[x] == "free") {
    $(".article-box").addClass("free");
  }
}// end categories append for loop
```

Create a box to put the list and the other elements in:

```
var box = $('<div>', { className: 'article-box' });
box.append([
  $('<h1>').html('<a href="#">' + response[x].title + '</a>'),
  $('<h3>').html('<a href="#">' + response[x].name + '</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + posted.toLocaleDateString()),
  list,
  $('<p>').text(extract)
]);
```

Put the box in the page:

```
$("#articles-feed").append(box);
```